# Xpages Extlib dataView control sets "display:none;" style when column has empty value

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, xpages-extlib

I have a xpage with Extension Library DataView control. I have defined several extra columns there.

```
<xe:dataView id="dataView1"         
    <xe:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="vMyView" />
    </xe:this.data>

    <xe:this.summaryColumn>
        <xe:viewSummaryColumn columnName="$DateFrom"
            columnTitle="Date From">
        </xe:viewSummaryColumn>
    </xe:this.summaryColumn>

    <xe:this.extraColumns>
        <xe:viewExtraColumn columnName="$DateTo"
            styleClass="hidden-xs" headerStyleClass="hidden-xs" columnTitle="Date To"
            style="hidden-xs">
        </xe:viewExtraColumn>
        <xe:viewExtraColumn columnName="$Information"
            columnTitle="Information">
        </xe:viewExtraColumn>           
    </xe:this.extraColumns>
</xe:dataView>
```

My view data source contains same cells where information is empty. Those cells are rendered with style="display:none;".

How can I avoid this attribute and display those empty cells? I'd like not to change my view to fill empty cells with i.e. "-" char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty column value gets rendered with `style="display:none;"`:

[image]

You can avoid this if you add a custom converter to your column definition and replace an empty value by a space:

```xml
<xe:viewExtraColumn columnName="$Information"
    columnTitle="Information">
    <xe:this.converter>
        <xp:customConverter>
            <xp:this.getAsString><![CDATA[#{javascript:value == "" ? " " : value}]]></xp:this.getAsString>
            <xp:this.getAsObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:value}]]></xp:this.getAsObject>
        </xp:customConverter>
    </xe:this.converter>
</xe:viewExtraColumn>
```

It gets rendered to a "normal" grid cell without `display:none` then:

[image]

The code for getAsObject doesn't matter as long as the cell is not editable. So it's OK to just leave the value as it is.

Comment: Thanks for help. I had to change the getAsString section to `value == "" ? " " : I18n.toString(value, "yyyy-MM-dd")` because I use dates in the column.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a converter to "fake" some content, you could also adjust the css. Just implement

```
.lotusTable TD {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

in a style sheet resource used in your custom control(s).
So you also won't have to apply a converter to every potentially empty column.

Comment: This table is not rendered with .lotusTable class. I've changed css to follow yours class entry but the table was treated as text without table cells

Comment: My bad, I assumed you'd be using the OneUI (oneuiv2.1-default) theme - this already formats basically everything with built-in classes, so "addressing" single elements is easy. But just check the HTML, I'm sure you will find a pattern and can amend the css selector accordingly - or specify an own class name to your extraColumns via their styleClass property.